# Bokeh TapTool doesnt work for area glyphs

Tags: python-3.x, bokeh

Tap tool doesn't seem to work with area plots. Is there an alternative?
Sample code below
Bokeh Version: '2.0.2'

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.models import TapTool, CustomJS, VArea


p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400)
p.grid.minor_grid_line_color = '#eeeeee'

area = p.varea(x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        y1=[2, 6, 4, 3, 5],
        y2=[1, 4, 2, 2, 3],name="temp")

p.add_tools(TapTool(callback=CustomJS(code="console.log('taptool')")))
show(p)

# Nothing comes up
# It works with other glyphs for instance a circle

area = p.circle(x=20,y=20,size=15,)
p.add_tools(TapTool(callback=CustomJS(code="console.log('taptool')"))) 
show(p) # works as expected
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is an alternative. You can use polygons instead of the Varea. With polygons you have to use another syntax but you can create the same figures and the TapTool is working.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure show, output_notebook
from bokeh.models import TapTool, CustomJS
output_notebook()

p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400)
#p.grid.minor_grid_line_color = '#eeeeee'

p.multi_polygons(xs=[[ [ [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1] ]]],
                 ys=[[ [ [1, 4, 2, 2, 3, 5, 3, 4, 6, 2] ]]])

p.circle(x=20,y=20,size=15,)

p.add_tools(TapTool(callback=CustomJS(code="console.log('taptool')"))) 
show(p)
```

I also tried a solutions with patches and areas and I don't know why it is not working. Did you think about opening an issue on github?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I havent had time to implement your suggestion. I'll check it coming two days and let you know.

Comment: It was a bit tricky to replicate stacked areas with multi polygons, but I got it to work. And yes the tap tool is working too. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Following mosc9575 answer, I switched to multipolygon glyphs to plot a stacked area. Following is my code to replicate example: https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/stacked_area.html

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.models import TapTool, CustomJS
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from bokeh.palettes import brewer
from functools import reduce

output_file("patch.html")

N = 10
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, 100, size=(15, N))).add_prefix("y")


def rec_add(a, b):
    a = df[a] if isinstance(a, str) else a
    df[b] = a + df[b]
    return df[b]


reduce(rec_add, df.columns)

names = ["y%d" % i for i in range(N)]
p = figure(x_range=(0, len(df) - 1), y_range=(0, 800))
p.multi_polygons(
    xs=[[[np.concatenate([df.index.values, df.index.values[::-1]])]]] * 10,
    ys=[
        [
            [
                np.concatenate(
                    [
                        df[f"y{i}"].values,
                        df[f"y{i-1}"].values[::-1] if i > 0 else np.zeros((len(df),)),
                    ]
                )
            ]
        ]
        for i in range(len(df.columns))
    ],
    color=brewer["Spectral"][N],
)
p.add_tools(
    TapTool(callback=CustomJS(code="console.log(cb_data.source.selected.indices)")) 
)

show(p)
```